# Integrate Storybook with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, storybook

I am trying to integrate a very simple React app written in TypeScript with Storybook. I tried to follow several issues on the Storybook issue list, but can't tell what is the latest information. When I try to run the Storybook, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./.storybook/config.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../stories' in 
'react-mobx-mui-ts-seed/.storybook' @ ./.storybook/config.js 6:4-25
```

Can someone please point me to where I may be going wrong? The full project is available on Github here: https://github.com/archfirst/react-mobx-mui-ts-seed

Here's my webpack.config.js for Storybook:

```
const path = require('path');

const SRC_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '../src');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.tsx$/, loader: 'ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }]
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: [SRC_PATH, 'node_modules']
    },

    plugins: []
};
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I have this working now. You can visit the Github project link for the updated working code.

Comment: I just checked out your code. Both `npm start` and `npm run storybook` fails. :-( I'm running Node v8.9.1

Comment: Haven't touched this code in a while - both storybook and material ui have undergone several releases after this and `npm install` may be taking in the latest versions. Try locking the versions in package.json by removing the '^' in version numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It didn't work, unfortunately.